# Converting RDD to Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I  am trying to convert an RDD to a dataframe, but I keep getting a mismatched input error. What do I need to change?

```
 from pyspark.sql.functions import col
 from pyspark.sql import Row 
 from pyspark.sql.types import * 
 from pyspark.sql.functions import desc 
 from pyspark.sql.functions import SparkContext
 Text = "/content/birds.txt"
 Words = sc.textFile(Text).flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 
 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
 print(Words)

  # Convert word-count RDD to dataframe with 2 columns ["Name","Number"]
  
  rwdf = words.toDF("Name", "Number")
  rwdf.show(5)
```

Comment: your RDD is Messaage, not words.

Comment: `rwdf = Words.toDF(["Name", "Number"])`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I can't believe it was just that simple of an error.